# What is the actual use of helpers in CodeIgniter if library can do the same thing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am little bit confused about helpers and libraries both are do the same thing and helpers can do all those work which can a libraries do then what is the use of library and how can we decide where to use helper and where to use library?

Comment: IMO helpers are just some utility functions that would need during building an application like some string functions, array manipulations etc. A library achieves a much bigger perspective and mostly a business functionality, like making the user download his bank account statement in an excel format for which you would use a PHPExcel library.

Comment: Yea right but i want to know about custom function suppose i want to create a function i.e add() this for this i could use custom helper and custom library too so can you please tell me which i should prefer

Comment: Ok, what does `add()` do? Adds 2 numbers?

Comment: Yes its simply add 2 numbers so what i have to prefer helper or library and why?

Comment: Helper because it's just a utility function.

Comment: But why helper? we can use library as will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries are groups of related functions. So for example say you want to connect and work with Twitter. You might create a Twitter Library with all associated Twitter connectivity/retrieval functions. You wouldn't however create a Twitter helper as there are simply too many elements / functions required/involved.

You could in theory put all the twitter functions in a single helper file however that is the key between procedural and OOP. Libraries are classes, helpers (with multiple functions) would be procedural. And that is a much wider debate !!

Helper functions can be called anywhere in your code - so if you need to use the helpers in say a View and a controller they are available globally.